# Why are my views arguments not being handled properly?

Tags: views

I'm using Views 2 to rewrite the output of a specific field, which looks like this:

```
<a href="highlights1/[nid]/[field_uclw_value]">
  <span class="bold capitalized">[title]</span>
</a>
```

The link is generated as `http://www.xxxx.edu/highlights1/12499/Yes`, which I is correct. The view is at `/highlights1`, argument 1 is `12499`, and argument 2 is `Yes`.

But Drupal is not finding the page because its looking for the full path and NOT stripping & passing the arguments to the view named hightlights1.

These two args *are* defined in the referenced view, so why are they not being sent to the view?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a page display for your hightlights1 view with a path of `highlights1/%/%` set up?

Edit the path of your view's page display and ensure it's `highlights1/%/%` -- the percent signs each represent an argument for views to collect from the path and use.

Comment: As you can see below, I DO have that defined.  Basic settings
Name: Page
Title: None
Style: Unformatted
Row style: Semantic Views : Fields
Use AJAX: No
Use pager: No
Items to display: 10
Distinct: No
Access: Unrestricted
Caching: None
Exposed form in block: No
Header: None
Footer: None
Empty text: None
CSS class: None
Theme: Information
Page settings
Path: highlights1/%/%
Menu: No menu